# Show that the pushout of this specific simplicial map induces an isomorphism on the $n$th simplicial homotopy group.

Tags: limits-colimits, simplicial-stuff, higher-homotopy-groups

Let $n \geq 0$. Consider a pushout square in the category of simplicial sets as follows:

$$\begin{array} ~
\Lambda^{n+2}_{i} & \stackrel{}{\longrightarrow} & X \\
\downarrow{} & & \downarrow{f} \\
\partial \Delta^{n+2} & \stackrel{}{\longrightarrow} & Y,  
\end{array}
$$

where $\Lambda^{n+2}_{i}$ denotes the $(n+2,i)$-horn and $\partial \Delta^{n+2}$ denotes the boundary of the standard $(n+2)$-simplex.

I need to show that the simplicial map $f \colon X \to Y$ induces an isomorphism $f_{*} \colon \pi_{n}(X,x) \to \pi_{n}(Y,fx)$ for any choice of basepoint $x \in X$. How would I go about proving this?